# Any editor as convenient as that of stackexchange Physics

Tags: editors

Stackexchange physics has a very nice real-time editor of latex form formula.
Writing notes in this editor apparently is more efficient than using a normal latex editor.  Is there any similar project online or as a software which allow 
me to save edition and write in  A4 size pages ?  As writing notes, the full feature of latex is not that important.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please specify what you mean with "save edition".

Comment: I mean as I type in the stackexchange editor,  By clicking, I can only post it. I cannot even save it as a draft. Anyway,  I can copy the text to a local text editor then save it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Math SE and Physics SE calls mathjax server, so that they can be previewed in real-time. I suppose (correct me if I am wrong) doing this on local machine is both time-consuming and unnecessarily resource-wasting. Indeed, it may not be a good idea to auto-compile for every few seconds, as you may still be drafting something incomplete, and compilation errors are abundant.

I am satisfied with TeXstudio, where I write on the left and see compiled pdf on the right. I think this is convenient enough. Actually I am recently starting using Vim exclusively, and compile on command line whenever I see fit.

If you use Mac and really want a quasi-WYSIWYG editor, you may try [TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html). If you use Windows, do you consider [MathType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathType)?

If you would like editor to save your work every once in a while, there are many software that does this. TeXStudio has backup options; see preferences. Even TextEdit and Vim has auto-backup options. I am afraid this particular point is not relevant to this site.